# Setting default attribute values from database schema

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible for Laravel to set default attribute values for model from database, when creating object by `new Model` or `Model::create()`?

For example, I have table `clients` with some columns (name, sex, birthday, device, os, etc). I'm doing

```
$client = new Client::create(['name' => 'John Doe']);
```

and want `$client` object has all attributes, not only name. `dd($client->toArray());` returns

```
array:1 [▼
  "name" => "John Doe",
  "id" => 1
]
```

But `dd(Client::find(1)` returns

```
array:11 [▼
  "id" => 1
  "name" => "John Doe"
  "birthday" => null
  "sex" => 1
  "device" => ""
  "os" => ""
]
```

Yes, i could set `protected $attributes` property in model, but it is not what i'm looking for. I want this to be fetched from database schema.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `__construct()` function to merge in any missing attributes.

So in your model...

```
protected $defaults = [
    'sex' => 1,
    'device' => 'AAA',
    'os' => 'BBB',
];

public function __construct($attributes = [])
{
    $attributes = array_merge($this->defaults, $attributes);

    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

Comment: as i said, it is not what i'm looking for. for example, [phpactiverecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) could set attributes automatically. btw, if you set `$attributes` property it will work out of box without overriding constructor